# Django - Connect to other database for testing

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, automated-tests, models

Hi am trying to connect to my dev database during the Django test phase, instead of using the default test database created by Django.

My question is 
1) How do I make connection to my dev database during the test phase? 
2) How do I connect the models and the dev database during the test phase?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

Just setup in settings what database you want to use with django. Then you should just be able to `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect to different database during testing, you can use `.using()` to select a database

say, you have:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'NAME': 'app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'postgres_user',
    'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
  },
  'users': {
    'NAME': 'user_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'mysql_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
  }
}
```

you can select a database like:

```
Author.objects.using('users').all()
```